# first pager in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, slide

I am using the fragments FragmentStateAdapterPager to go, but I have a problem.

I have a listivew with 5 items, if I give in element 3 in the ViewPager shows me from the first fragment.

My main question is how I can do to put the first piece that was selected in the listview in ViewPager using FramentStateAdapterPager.

I'm trying using the getItem method, but when you open the slide displays me from the first element, and the idea is that you visualize from the selected position.

Any idea?

Comment: You have to persist the pagenumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open any slide of view pager by this function:

```
int indexOfTheSlideYouWantToOpen = 2;
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.house_pager);
...
...
pager.setCurrentItem(indexOfTheSlideYouWantToOpen);
```

Viewpager will open third screen, on activity launch.

And if you want to save the last screen which view pager had displayed then user `bundle`

```
override `onSaveInstanceState` and get `Bundle savedInstanceState` in `onCreateView`
```